# Selenium WebDriverBackedSelenium implementation for ruby

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently working on automated testing project. I'm trying to migrate from selenium rc to selenium 2 webdriver but I want to keep the old test classes. I have searched about this and found WebDriverBackedSelenium but it seems to be only in java.
So is there any implementation out there or has anyone already implemented it?

Answer (score 2):

We're working on exposing the Java WebDriverBackedSelenium as part of the Selenium Server, which will give us this functionality in all supported languages. Watch [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1734).